# MatOption how to simulate selection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat select with the multiple option set (a multi-select). When I select one of the options, I need to disable other options. How can I do that in checkDeleted() function, or in refresh() function? Is there a method of MatOption class that manually switch selected field? Here is my HTML :

```
<mat-select #statusSelect [(ngModel)]="statuses" (selectionChange)="refresh()" multiple>
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let status of statuses"
          #statusOptSelect
          [value]="status.id"
          [disabled]="!checkDeleted(statusOptSelect)"
        >
          {{ status.name }}
        </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And ts code:

```
  public checkDeleted(el: MatOption): boolean {
    if (this.filter.statuses.includes(EStatus.DELETED) && el.value !== EStatus.DELETED) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: `[disabled]="isDeletedStatusChecked && status.id != deletedStatus.id"`

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="statuses"` => `[(ngModel)]="selectedStatusIds"`